# Debugging a memory leak in a long-running mono/C# application

Tags: c#, mono

I have a C# program that runs on an Ubuntu VM as a server using mono 5.10. Every now and then, the program starts using lots of memory until it eventually crashes. It can often take days before such a memory leak occurs, and I haven't been able to reproduce the issue locally.

For the past few days, I've used the mono log profiler to be able to collect heapshots on demand. This has given me a 15Gb+ file. I managed to get a heapshot from when the memory leak occurs, which displays as follows in the Xamarin profiler:

[image: HeapShot summary in the Xamarin profiler]

Running `mprof-report` gives a similarly unhelpful report.

Neither really help debug the problem. Obviously there's something going on with the threadpool, but it seems like there is no way of figuring out what.

Being able to see where the objects are allocated might help, but that requires enabling `alloc` in the profiler, which is not possible because of the file size it will produce.

What is causing the massive amount of `IThreadPoolWorkItem`s? The app is using 30-40% CPU, so it doesn't seem like tasks are being scheduled more quickly than the CPU can handle.

Is there a way to list the objects referenced by the ThreadPool jobs? That would at least allow me to identify what piece of code is being run so much. `mprof-report` only shows inverse references as far as I can see, which isn't very helpful as the `IThreadPoolWorkItem`s are obviously owned by the `ThreadPool` itself.

**Update:** The tasks aren't (disk) IO bound. While leaking, the reads are in the 10s of kbs per second, which shouldn't be saturating the disk.

On second thought: if there were a lot of tasks scheduled, shouldn't I be seeing lots of individual `IThreadPoolWorkItem` objects too? Since `IThreadPoolWorkItem` isn't a struct, there should be a separate entry for the actual object and `IThreadPoolWorkItem[]` would just be an array of pointers. So this would suggest that those `IThreadPoolWorkItem[]`s are just arrays of (mostly) `null` pointers.

**Update:** `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` shows 2 worker threads and 0 completion port threads are active, which seems to indicate that the `ThreadPool` is doing just fine. Custom logging also indicates that once again, I'm not scheduling too many tasks and the tasks that are scheduled are finished quickly.

Comment: `The app is using 30-40% CPU, so it doesn't seem like tasks are being scheduled more quickly than the CPU can handle.` Or possibly the `Task`s are IO bound?

Comment: @mjwills doesn't seem likely, as I don't see any IO spikes in the monitoring. But I'll make sure to double-check next time the memory leak happens.

Answer (score 0):

try set MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU variable to 200 before run mono

```
MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=200 mono MyApp.exe
```

By default mono has 2 working threads in ThreadPool